# Not getting first parameter when sending a message from main to renderer

Tags: electron

I'm new to electron and am trying to send a message with parameters from the main process to the renderer.

Here is my main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let win;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
    });
    win.loadFile("index.html");
    win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', 'my message', 'my second parameter');
});
```

and my preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  ipcRenderer: {
    send: (channel, data) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, data),
    on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
  }
});
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Test
</body>
</html>
```

and my renderer.js

```
electron.ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (evt, message, secondParameter) {
    console.log(message); // Returns: 'my message'
    console.log(secondParameter); // Returns: 'my second parameter'
});
```

`console.log(message);` gives me `my second parameter`

and `console.log(secondParameter);` gives me `undefined`

And here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "msg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.1.3"
  }
}
```

What do I need to change to get the parameters working properly?

In case it helps, the project was set up using these commands:

```
npm init -y
npm install --save-dev electron
```

and I'm running on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change a few things:

1. Not a requirement in this scenario, but it's a good idea to start talking to the renderer/view once the DOM has loaded. (This is practically a necessity if you are building an app that has a UI that reacts to IPC messages; you need the DOM to be ready before you can react). You can do that by waiting on the `"dom-ready"` event like so:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let win;

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });
    win.loadFile("index.html");

    win.webContents.once("dom-ready", async () => {
        win.webContents.openDevTools();
        win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', {
            key1: 'my message', 
            key2: 'my second parameter'
        });
    });    
});
```

2. Get rid of the renderer.js file. When you use a preload file, the contents are injected into your view.
3. Using `contextBridge`, create the listener function from `window` + 'electron' (first parameter in `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld`) + 'ipcRenderer' (property name in the object/second parameter of `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld`) directly in your HTML.

[The docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) list the listener function of **ipcRenderer.on** as an event and `...args` as `any[]`, but that doesn't seem to work. I've always used an object I send in my message and that way I can pass multiple values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.electron.ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (event) {
            console.log(event.key1); // Returns: 'my message'
            console.log(event.key2); // Returns: 'my second parameter'
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've written up a few lengthy [blog posts](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/) about Electron too that may help if you have additional questions.